# Pillow, draw text not working for bar-code font

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am using pillow to draw some texts in my images. So far so good, this is working for normal fonts. But when I use this [bare-code font](https://www.1001fonts.com/idahc39m-code-39-barcode-font.html) pillow is not drawing anything. Also no error occurs, any ideas?

This is code snippet shows loading the font and drawing the text, the `font_file` (path) is correct.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file, line.styles.font_size)
# Drawing the text in my image
self.draw_inst.text((pos_x, pos_y), line.text, font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
```

The code is working for every other font I use.

Comment: What platform/OS are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 10, with anaconda.

Comment: I do very little with Windows, but would point out that TrueType fonts require the `imaging_ft` service https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html so I imagine you must install something from here https://www.freetype.org **I am only guessing though.** Also, I **think** the font you are using is only available in point-size 26 - so maybe check that too,

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. I will give that a try. First the point-size. I also thought about that, but because Windows can show the font with any size I didn't follow up.

Comment: So sadly the font-size had no impact.

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with the font, I use now this font https://www.1001fonts.com/barcode-font-font.html and it works as expected.